# XPATH: Parse table, next row but same column

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am parsing a website that has the following table structure

```
<tr>
  <td>Description1</td>
  <td>Description2</td>
  <td>Description3</td>
<\tr>
<tr>
  <td>Price1</td>
  <td>Price2</td>
  <td>Price3</td>
<\tr>
```

What i need is to match Description2 to Price2 etc..,  going down the list without using any hard coded text or classes.  Currently i have a foreach loop that cycles through all the descriptions.   I tried using position() like so:

```
"../following-sibling::td[position()]"
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this meets your requirement of no *"hard coded text or classes"*, but this will group the column headers, with the column values:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("...");

var columns = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("table/tr[position() = 1]/td")
    .Select((n, i) => new {
        Description = n.InnerText,
        Values = n.ParentNode.SelectNodes(String.Format("following-sibling::tr/td[position() = {0}]", i + 1)).Select(v => v.InnerText)
    });
```

You can iterate through that like so:

```
foreach(var column in columns)
{
    Console.WriteLine(column.Description);

    foreach(var value in column.Values)
        Console.WriteLine("  " + value);
}
```

Which will produce:

```
Description1
    Price1
Description2
    Price2
Description3
    Price3
```

If you just want the Description2 column, you could just add a Where clause like this:

```
var columns = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("table/tr[position() = 1]/td")
    .Select((n, i) => new {
        Description = n.InnerText,
        Values = n.ParentNode.SelectNodes(String.Format("following-sibling::tr/td[position() = {0}]", i + 1)).Select(v => v.InnerText)
    })
    .Where(c => c.Description == "Description2");
```